# How does AppMakr and Mobile Roadie work?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, user-interface

How does [AppMakr](http://www.appmakr.com/) and [Mobile Roadie](http://www.mobileroadie.com/) work?
Do they load native UI in their apps or is it webapp based? And how do they update their content within the app?

Answer (score 1):

Our platform builds native UI apps, we do not use web views. We pull in XML feeds to update design and content. All changes (design + content) you make from the CMS update the app in real time. If you have any additional questions, feel free to email hello@mobileroadie.com and we're happy to answer.

Michael Schneider
CEO, Mobile Roadie

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is http://www.MobileAppLoader.com. We have Native Apps that can render HTML upon request. We update our App remotely via XML.

Answer (score 0):

Folks should also consider www.Snappii.com  We build native apps which can be updated via our website CMS.  Point and click development with no programming at all

Alex Bakman
President